# Maya closed surface from 3d points

Tags: python, mayavi

I have large set of 3d points (200k) that model an object which I'm plotting with plot3d(). Whilst the program doesn't crash and still runs, it is slow to pan around. Are there any built in ways I can render only the points which are visible? Or better still, create a surface over the exterior points?

I have read that one way to speed it up is to create a single VTK object with all the points in it, rather than one object per point.

```
x,y,z,_,s = zip(*voxels)

print len(x) # 180k
points3d(x, y, z,s,scale_factor=0.8)
show()
```

Comment: can you give an example of your current source code?

Comment: i put what i thought was relevant

Answer (score 0):

Well, this could be a solution, depending on how your data looks like.
You could calculate the complex hull of your point set i.e.:

```
import numpy as np

from mayavi import mlab
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull

x = np.random.rand(200000)
y = np.random.rand(200000)
z = np.random.rand(200000)
points = np.column_stack((x, y, z))

ch = ConvexHull(points)
hull_ids = ch.vertices

mlab.points3d(x[hull_ids], y[hull_ids], z[hull_ids])
mlab.show()
```

An alternative would be to calculate an alpha shape using a Delaunay function. This is very well explained here for example:
http://sgillies.net/blog/1155/the-fading-shape-of-alpha/